# Fail to load media files in Django(on Windows)

Tags: django, django-views, python-2.7

When i'm trying to load 
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/javascripts/bg-input.png

I get a 500 http response saying:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /media/javascripts/bg-input.png
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/javascripts/bg-input.png
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: T:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py in enum_types, line 250
Python Executable:  T:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:    
['T:\\djangos\\deadline',
 'T:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 'T:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.7.egg',
 'T:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-2.3.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'T:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'T:\\Python27\\lib',
 'T:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'T:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'T:\\Python27',
 'T:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'T:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']
Server time:    星期二, 7 二月 2012 13:33:53 +0800
```

Unicode error hint
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: ����/x

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/javascripts/bg-input.png

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'pagination',
 'deadline.reg',
 'deadline.helpers',
 'deadline.users',
 'deadline.tasks',
 'deadline.comments']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "T:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "T:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py" in serve
  54.     mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
File "T:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py" in guess_type
  294.         init()
File "T:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py" in init
  355.             db.read_windows_registry()
File "T:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py" in read_windows_registry
  260.             for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
File "T:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py" in enum_types
  250.                     ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /media/javascripts/bg-input.png
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This happens when i am running on windows. In ubuntu it works fine.

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = 'T:/djangos/deadline/media/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Comment: You unicode error hint appears as [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).  Perhaps it's really not unicode?

Comment: I have no idea where this string comes from.

Comment: Can you see anything else than "����" in the original error message?  There are chinese (or japanese) characters that correctly appear in your post.

Comment: There's something odd in your configuration.  If the URL is actually mapped to a static PNG file, then somehow your Django configuration is trying to load that as some kind of text.  Can you post the relevant URL configuration?

Comment: URL configuration has been added to this question. The PNG file exists and in ubuntu it works just fine. I am wondering if Django has some potential problems on Windows 7.

Comment: The `mimetypes` module is loading some information from the Windows registry, which has been in Unicode (not ASCII) in Windows NT-derived OSes since for almost 20 years.  I'd take a look at the code in the `mimetypes` module and print relevant values to see what content triggers this encoding exception.  I recommend posting this issue to the Django mailing list.  If you have an old version of Django, I'd also update (assuming this is possible) to see if it still occurs in the latest release.